# Language Translation API

Tags: java, google-translate

How can i convert language in my Java? Is there any API exist, which convert any language to any other language? I am using Google Translate API, but it giving me below exception.

```
java.lang.Exception: [google-api-translate-java] Error retrieving translation.
at com.google.api.GoogleAPI.retrieveJSON(GoogleAPI.java:123)
at com.google.api.translate.Translate.execute(Translate.java:69)
at com.nextenders.client.beans.ruleengine.RuleEngineTest.main(RuleEngineTest.java:27)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
null
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(Unknown Source)
at com.google.api.GoogleAPI.retrieveJSON(GoogleAPI.java:107)
... 2 more
```

If anybody knows any API for translation, please tell me.

Comment: I had this error trying to launch my program through a proxy, is it your case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by the guy on [JavaRanch](http://www.coderanch.com/t/494510//java/language-translation-API#2226054), there is an issue with the connection to the API

Somewhere you will have specified a URL to connect to, something is blocking that, check you can access that address via ping